# Plotting multiple maps using GeoPandas

Tags: geopandas, matplotlib, plot, geodataframe

I have two GeoDataFrames. The first one have the administrative boundaries of the 25 regions of a country. The second one, the urban fabric of the same country.

```py
regions.head()

    COD    NAMEREG      ID  geometry
0   06     CAJAMARCA    6   MULTIPOLYGON (((175543.152 9154323.287, 175542...
1   14     LAMBAYEQUE   14  MULTIPOLYGON (((148.362 9224534.960, 85.995 92...
2   15     LIMA         15  MULTIPOLYGON (((395740.367 8562514.992, 395702...
3   02     ANCASH       2   MULTIPOLYGON (((261823.737 8840350.284, 261826...
4   04     AREQUIPA     4   MULTIPOLYGON (((891245.832 8110391.639, 891267...

urbfab.head()

    Area        geometry
0   124196.0    MULTIPOLYGON (((1714054.886 9088365.957, 17143...
1   124196.0    MULTIPOLYGON (((1835848.391 9084645.865, 18361...
2   62098.0     MULTIPOLYGON (((1712843.236 9087713.270, 17131...
3   124196.0    MULTIPOLYGON (((1835363.081 9083054.193, 18356...
4   124196.0    MULTIPOLYGON (((1756044.734 9085140.825, 17563...
```

So, to plot both of them I use this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 16))

regions.plot(ax=ax, color='#ffffff', edgecolor='#6a6a6a', linewidth=2)
urbfab.plot(ax=ax, color='#000000', edgecolor='#000000')

_=ax.axis('off')
```

Which results in this image, which for basic purposes is OK:
[image]

But I want to know if is it possible to get an image like this, where any region is shown separately.
[image]

(Of course, this is for example purposes only, that is why I plotted only 3 regions. It was produced in QGIS)

Answer (score 7):

I usually plot multiple maps as following.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 5, figsize=(25, 25))
axs = axs.flatten()

for idx in range(len(regions)):
    regions.iloc[[idx]].plot(ax=axs[idx], color='#ffffff', edgecolor='#6a6a6a', linewidth=2)
    urbfab.iloc[[idx]].plot(ax=axs[idx], color='#000000', edgecolor='#000000')
    axs[idx].set_title(f"{regions.iloc[idx]['NAMEREG']} #{idx}")
    axs[idx].axis('off')
plot.show()
```

Comment: I get this mesage: `TypeError: no numeric data to plot`.

Comment: `[[idx]]` instead of `[idx]`. I updated the above.

Comment: I have a problem with this line: `axs[idx].set_title(f'{regions.iloc[idx]['NAMEREG']} #{idx}')`. I get this message:   `SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '['`

Comment: @JoseRojas Try `f"{regions.iloc[idx]['NAMEREG']} #{idx}"`, this way the quotation marks no longer collide.

Comment: I tried it but I still have a problem. I described it in this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404786/get-multiple-maps-from-just-one-in-python?noredirect=1#comment660818_404786)