# Get multiple maps from just one in Python

Tags: python

I have two geodataframes (`prov`, which have administrative boundaries for some provinces of a country, and `mok`, which have the urban fabric of those provinces), which plotted in one single map looks like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

prov.plot(ax=ax, color='#ffffff', edgecolor='#abacab', linewidth=1)
mok.plot(ax=ax, color='#000000', edgecolor='#000000')

_=ax.axis('off')
```

[image]

What I want is to get an image where the provinces are side by side, in an orderly fashion. Like this one below, but with the urban fabric layer on top.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 5, figsize=(25, 25))
axs = axs.flatten()

for idx in range(len(prov)):
    prov.iloc[[idx]].plot(ax=axs[idx], color='#ffffff', edgecolor='#6a6a6a', linewidth=2)
    axs[idx].axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

So, I had tried with this code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 5, figsize=(25, 25))
axs = axs.flatten()

for idx in range(len(prov)):
   prov.iloc[[idx]].plot(ax=axs[idx], color='#ffffff', edgecolor='#6a6a6a', linewidth=2)
   mok.iloc[[idx]].plot(ax=axs[idx], color='#6a6a6a', edgecolor='#6a6a6a', linewidth=0.1)
   axs[idx].axis('off')

plt.show()
```

But I get a nonsensical image, like the one I show below. Both geodataframes are in the same coordinate system, EPSG:32718.
[image]

Is there a way to obtain the image that I'm looking for?

(BTW, I would also like to know if it is possible to put the name of the provinces above their figure)

The gdfs looks like this:

```
prov.head()

    COD    NAMEPROV     ID  geometry
0   06     TRUJILLO     6   MULTIPOLYGON (((175543.152 9154323.287, 175542...
1   14     LAMBAYEQUE   14  MULTIPOLYGON (((148.362 9224534.960, 85.995 92...
2   15     LIMA         15  MULTIPOLYGON (((395740.367 8562514.992, 395702...
3   02     ANCASH       2   MULTIPOLYGON (((261823.737 8840350.284, 261826...
4   04     CAJAMARCA    4   MULTIPOLYGON (((891245.832 8110391.639, 891267...

mok.head()

    Area        geometry
0   124196.0    MULTIPOLYGON (((1714054.886 9088365.957, 17143...
1   124196.0    MULTIPOLYGON (((1835848.391 9084645.865, 18361...
2   62098.0     MULTIPOLYGON (((1712843.236 9087713.270, 17131...
3   124196.0    MULTIPOLYGON (((1835363.081 9083054.193, 18356...
4   124196.0    MULTIPOLYGON (((1756044.734 9085140.825, 17563...)
```

Comment: Did you import geopandas or something else before getting to where you are stuck in your code?

Comment: @PolyGeo `pandas` (as pd), `geopandas` (as gpd) and `matplotlib` (as plt)

Comment: I think those imports should be part of the code snippet that you present.

Comment: But is not possible to charge the geodataframes without loading GeoPandas, right?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/404778/50025

Comment: I'm using the code that you write as an answer in that link. But it get me the nonsensical image I refer to in this question.

Comment: `prov` is `regions` and `mok` is `urbfab`

Comment: Plotting extent has been changed by plotting `mok`. There are two solution. 1. set plotting extent with `set_xlim()` and `set_ylim()` in each iterations. 2. clip `mok` with each province polygons before plot.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I still don't know how to do either of the two things you mention, but I'll look around here. If I come up with a solution I will post it.